# Filtering using multiple wildcards

Tags: makefile, filtering, wildcard, gnu-make, glob

I've git a project where, at some point in its Makefile, I'm filtering out stuff from a certain directory:

```
relevant = $(filter-out irrelevant/%,$^)
```

Now I want to use this in a `VPATH`-enabled environment. So the paths of my dependencies in `$^` might not start with `irrelevant` any more, but instead something like `../src/irrelevant` or similar.

Is there a way to filter-out anything that *contains* `irrelevant`, in any position? I.e. something like the following?

```
relevant = $(filter-out %irrelevant/%,$^)
```

This doesn't work, since apparently patterns for `filter-out` can contain only a single `%` wildcard. I know I could possibly achieve this via a shell invocation, grep or whatever, but I was hoping for some combinations of functions inside the Makefile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
relevant = $(foreach a,$^,$(if $(findstring irrelevant,$a),,$a))
```